# Java: Socket closing after try-catch blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am attempting a client/server type chat box (using GUI's). I won't get into details of the multi-threading I used in the program since I believe it is not part of the problem (I hope not) and it will be good amount of code to post. Anyways, for both my client and my server I create a socket, and some other stream classes within a try block, and some reason the sockets close after the catch blocks. PS I do NOT call socket.close() method anywhere that could end if early

Server, this is ran into a constructor of one of my class. It breaks down into, my main has the actually server stuff on a different thread, (like my previous post) it is a fix so that the gui can load and run the server stuff without one waiting on the other. Anyways, without all that detail, here is my code

```
    public ChatAppProtocol(Socket sock) 
    {
        super("ChatAppServer");
        // this also has a clas var of Socket
        this.sock = sock;

        try (
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(this.sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.sock.getInputStream())) ;
        ) 
        {
           // first stream of a string is the username loging in from client 
           String name = input.readLine();
           // this returns false, so its not closed
           System.out.println("closed?: " + this.sock.isClosed());

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // closed after the catch blocks  before methods even ends
        // p.s. i also plan on using the socket in another method but can't since it closes
        System.out.println("closed?: " +this.sock.isClosed());

    }
```

now my client

```
@FXML
private void login() 
{
        this.name = this.username.getText().trim();
        this.portnum = Integer.parseInt(this.port.getText());
        this.name = this.username.getText().trim();
        this.ipaddr = this.ip.getText().trim();

        try (t
            Socket socket = new Socket(this.ipaddr, this.portnum);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        ) 
        {
            this.sock = socket;
            output.println(this.name);
            // this returns false, not closed
            System.out.println("closed?: " +this.sock.isClosed());
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Problem at ip: " + this.ipaddr);
            System.exit(1);
        } 
         // PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // returns true here, closes before methods end and i cant reuse it
        System.out.println("IS IT CLOSED!!!!!! " + this.sock.isClosed());
    }
}
```

so, any reason why both this different class, different files, different project sockets close after try-catch blocks? Can't find answer online, and been on it for a while and I am stuck. I found out about this problem after seeing this on the server side console

```
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:943)
at chatappserver.ChatAppProtocol.run(ChatAppProtocol.java:62)
```

Comment: Have you looked at how `try-with-resources` works?

Comment: @biziclop I have no in a while, I am going off some example code online, ill read up on it now, if the try is causing the problem, what can be a work around?

Comment: "[The try-with-resources statement **ensures that each resource is closed** at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thank you, but what can I do as a work around? my IDE wont allow me to allocate my class socket variable within the try, it only allows me to do it when I create the variable within the try block

Comment: @TannerSummers Show us the code you IDE won't allow and tell us what error it gives you.

Comment: as I commented to someone else below, here is a SS of when I try to allocate the class Socket variable
EDIT: give me a second on this actually


https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TiGzeynAl2QVF4Qk9FZWNuRzQ/view?usp=sharing

@DavidSchwartz

Comment: Nevermind DavidSchwartz, I got it working thanks too DanielGibbs, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're creating `socket` with the brackets of the `try` block, it is automatically closed upon exiting the block. Instead, try creating it inside the block itself and it shouldn't be closed:

```
try {
    this.sock = new Socket(this.ipaddr, this.portnum);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    output.println(this.name);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Problem at ip: " + this.ipaddr);
    System.exit(1);
}
// this.sock should still be open at this point.
```

Have a read of the Java tutorial on [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more information on why you're getting your current behaviour.

Comment: This why wont work for me. The try block wont let me do the this.sock = new blank blank. I get IDE errors, it seems like it only allows me to create a variable then allocate it vs doing it this, :( sucks I know hats why I did it the way I did or else this would be best!

Comment: I get: 

"illegal start of type

= expected
----

Comment: illegal start of type

= expected

on my netbeans 8 IDE

Comment: And you're sure you're using the same syntax as in my answer? Could you upload a screenshot of the error?

Comment: here is ss, sorry I don't know any other way to give it to you, also ignore all my weird extra code lol

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TiGzeynAl2QVF4Qk9FZWNuRzQ/view?usp=sharing

@DanielGibbs

Comment: You're still using **brackets** not **braces**. Make sure you make the code look like it does in my answer, using braces.

Comment: It works! sorry about the braces the first time @DanielGibbs, I missed those. Also the fact it is almost 5am in the morning does not help. Can you explain to me why the example I was going off use braces in the first place vs the way you did it? Thanks so much

Comment: Have a read of the link I put in the answer; it explains why your socket was being closed.

Comment: I will read it in the morning, I am headed to bed, does the article also explain why it can be try(){} or try{}? that is my last question for the night I thank you very much for all your help man

Comment: You can read other parts of the same section of the tutorial if you need explanation on what a `try` block is.

Comment: One last thing: I think I may have confused you a bit with my terminology; brackets are `(` and `)` (also known as parentheses) and braces are `{` and `}` (sometimes known as "curly brackets").

Answer (score 0):

You are using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is roughly an equivalent of:

```
    try
    {
        this.sock = new Socket(this.ipaddr, this.portnum));
        output.println(this.name);
        // this returns false, not closed
        System.out.println("closed?: " +this.sock.isClosed());
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Problem at ip: " + this.ipaddr);
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        if (this.sock != null)
          this.sock.close();
    }
```

Just initialize the socket outside the resources clause of `try (...)` and it won't get closed

Comment: @Dariuzs getting rid of the braces fixes it :)